# Error configuring Spring Tool Suite Dependency

Tags: spring, maven-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I've created new Spring Template Project- Spring MVC project.
IDE: Spring Tool Suite 3.2.0

Using this tutorial here: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide

I've added build path external jars, but got this error. Did few things but error still exist.

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                </listener>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                    <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
                    </init-param>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

            </web-app>
```

Comment: can you post you pom ?

Comment: the above link doesn't work .

Comment: I cant attach photo to this app

Comment: copy the content of your Pom.xml , then edit this question `edit` , clik inside teh box, ctrl+k then ctrl+v...you don't have to attach a photo.

Comment: Hi please refer to answer below... pom.xml

Comment: you've should attached that to the question box not the answer

Comment: run `mvn eclipse:clean` and then run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: Done. But still same error

Comment: can you post your `web.xml`?

Comment: your configuration seems to be correct, how do you deploy to your server ?

Comment: run `clean package` on your project and run it on a server

Comment: How to make this project run using maven. Coz when I right click project - maven- there's no update maven dependency

Comment: Run on server a bit difficult coz company policy. I need to use localhost. This is my personal project.

Comment: right click `Configure` -->`Convert to Maven Project`

Comment: Ok. Will try tomorrow.  let you know later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>com.aza</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
                <name>e-commerce</name>
                <packaging>war</packaging>
                <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <properties>
                    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
                    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
                    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
                    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
                </properties>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                  <id>JBoss repository</id>
                  <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
             </repositories>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Spring -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                             </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- AspectJ -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Logging -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.15</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- @Inject -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Servlet -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Test -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.7</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalProjectnatures>
                                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                                </additionalProjectnatures>
                                <additionalBuildcommands>
                                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                                </additionalBuildcommands>
                                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </project>
```